# PHP: Transformation of array

Tags: php, arrays

There is the following array:

```
arr1 = array(array('xxx',3),array('yyy',2));
```

I need to transform it into the array `arr2`, where the number of occurrence of each entry is equal to the 2nd column value in array `arr1`. For instance, for the above given `arr1`, `arr2` should be the following:

```
arr2 = array(array('xxx'),array('xxx'),array('xxx'),array('yyy'),array('yyy'));
```

I wrote the following code, but my question is: *Is it possible to do the same in a simpler way?*

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($arr1); $i++) {
  for ($j=0; $j<$arr1[i][1]; $j++) {
     $arr2[] = array($arr1[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: A missing `$` before `arr2`, `i`, and `j` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is simpler and easier to read.

```
$arr1 = array(array('xxx', 3), array('yyy', 2));
$arr2 = array();

foreach ($arr1 as $arr)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $arr[1]; $i++)
    {
        $arr2[] = array($arr[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you mean $arr2[] = array($arr[$i]);

Comment: @KlausosKlausos I don't think he does - each `$arr` is an array with 2 items. `$arr[0]` is what you want to repeat.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($arr1 as $entry) {
    $arr2[] = array_fill(0, $entry[1], array($entry[0]));
}
$arr2 = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr2);
```

I wouldn't use it though. It's much less readable.